# PHP CLI with Symfony causing Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: php, linux, symfony

I have been doing a simple study into the [api-platform](https://api-platform.com/). Until today, everything was working fine, but then I upgraded the packages on my computer by running

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The upgrade also happened to update my `php` as seen below from running the command `cat /var/log/apt/history.log`

```bash
Start-Date: 2022-08-17  09:59:11
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Requested-By: mayatsa (1000)
Upgrade: php8.1-intl:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.1-mysql:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), tracker-extract:amd64 (2.3.3-2, 2.3.3-2ubuntu0.20.04.1), python3-dnspython:amd64 (1.16.0-1build1, 1.16.0-1ubuntu1), php-xdebug:amd64 (3.1.2+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-4+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+10, 3.1.5+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.1-xml:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.1-zip:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.1-common:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), libsnmp-base:amd64 (5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.4, 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.5), php8.1:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (104.0.5112.79-1, 104.0.5112.101-1), nodejs:amd64 (16.16.0-deb-1nodesource1, 16.17.0-deb-1nodesource1), php8.1-xdebug:amd64 (3.1.2+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-4+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+10, 3.1.5+2.9.8+2.8.1+2.5.5-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), tracker-miner-fs:amd64 (2.3.3-2, 2.3.3-2ubuntu0.20.04.1), libsnmp35:amd64 (5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.4, 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.5), php8.1-sqlite3:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.1-mbstring:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.1-readline:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.1-opcache:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2.36.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), php8.1-pgsql:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.1-cli:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.1-fpm:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2.36.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), php8.1-gd:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), php8.1-curl:amd64 (8.1.8-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, 8.1.9-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2.36.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2.36.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
End-Date: 2022-08-17  10:00:01
```

Currently, my `php` version is as follows

```bash
PHP 8.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2022 09:39:52) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

Now, when I run my the command `symfony console list` at the root of symfony project I get

```bash
signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316093/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-in-php), I was able to run this command `gdb $(which php8.1)` and then I typed `run /home/user/Documents/study/api-platform/bin/console` and got

```bash
Starting program: /usr/bin/php8.1 /home/user/Documents/study/api-platform/bin/console
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:384
384 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S: No such file or directory.
```

I am no C or C++ developer, so I am not sure what the error means exactly, apart from `No such file or directory` part.

I would appreciate any help here. Thank you

Comment: This may be a bit obvious but ...  have you tried to turn your computer off and on again?